# Keeping a square clipping volume square, regardless of viewport size in opengl?

Tags: opengl

I'm working through the OpenGL SuperBible 4th edition. There's a description of how, in a window that is tall and thin, if the viewport matches the dimensions of the window, but it is mapped to a clipping volume that's square, the image will appear distorted (tall and thin like the viewport).

The solution to keeping the image square is the following code:

```
// Establish clipping volume (left, right, bottom, top, near, far) 
aspectRatio = (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h; 
if (w <= h)       
    glOrtho (-100.0, 100.0, -100 / aspectRatio, 100.0 / aspectRatio, 1.0, -1.0);
else       
    glOrtho (-100.0 * aspectRatio, 100.0 * aspectRatio, -100.0, 100.0, 1.0, -1.0);
```

There is an explanation given for this code, but I just can't understand it. Why are we extending the height of the clipping volume according to aspectRatio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspect ratios in OpenGL that you need to be aware of:

1. the *viewport*'s aspect ratio, which is specified when you call `glViewport`
2. the *viewing frustum*'s aspect ratio, which is specified through your projection transformation, whether it's orthographic (e.g., set by `glOrtho`), or perspective (set by either `glFrustum`, or `gluPerspective` most often).

Now, to keep squares rendering as squares, the two aspect ratios need to match.  When you resize a window, you implicitly set the aspect ratio of the viewport with your call to `glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );`

Specifying the aspect ratio for the projection transformation is either explicit, like when you call `gluPerspective`, as its second parameter is the aspect ratio of the viewing frustum.  However, for calls like `glOrtho`, or `glFrustum`, the viewing frustum's aspect ratio is controlled by the width and height of the viewing volume.  Taking the orthographic case you mention (and the same discussion works for perspective projections), the width of the viewing volume here **right - left**, similarly, the height is **top - bottom**, and the ratio of those two quantities is the viewing volume's aspect ratio.

Now, remember that we need the two aspect ratios to match.  It's unlikely that we can modify the viewport's, as it's usually the case that you want to use all the pixels in the window, or not risk having objects clipped, so we're forced to modify the viewing volume's aspect ratio in order to get them to match.  We do that by either modifying the width or the height of the viewing volume based on the viewport's aspect ratio, which is what you see in the code you provided.  In particular, if the viewport's aspect ratio is greater than 1.0 (i.e., wider than tall), then we need to make our viewing volume wider, which is why we multiply **left** and **right** by the aspect ratio.  Similarly, if the viewport's aspect is less than 1.0, we need to make the viewing volume taller.  In this case, we use the reciprocal of the aspect ratio (which will be larger than 1.0), providing the appropriate scaling for **top** and **bottom**.

Comment: I think perhaps I don't really understand what the relationship is between the viewport and the viewing frustum. I think when I know that then I'll understand what you mean in your answer.

Comment: This is the best visual explanation of frustum to viewport mapping i could find: http://relativity.net.au/gaming/java/Frustum.html

Comment: @BeeBand Perhaps this [image](http://i.imgur.com/Bhu0PzJ.png) helps.  The _image plane_, or _image rectangle_, as it's sometimes called, is the rectangle defined by the sides of the viewing frustum on the near clipping plane.  OpenGL's viewport maps to the image rectangle, and those are the aspect ratios you need to keep consistent.  Here are some [notes](http://www.plunk.org/COEN-290/Notes/Week2.pdf) from a course I taught that also explain the relationship which you may find useful.