# opengl Draw Oval not Circle

Tags: c++, opengl, math, geometry, geometry-shader

if I call the function DrawFilledCircleo() it makes an oval and not a circle , even if i put glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); it always makes Oval

```
void drawFilledCircle(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat radius){
    int i;
    int triangleAmount = 20; //# of triangles used to draw circle

    //GLfloat radius = 0.8f; //radius
    GLfloat twicePi = 2.0f * PI;

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex2f(x, y); // center of circle
        for(i = 0; i <= triangleAmount;i++) { 
            glVertex2f(
                    x + (radius * cos(i *  twicePi / triangleAmount)), 
                y + (radius * sin(i * twicePi / triangleAmount))
            );
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

i tried different functions for drawing circles but it always makes Oval .

i placed it in :

```
static void Draw(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glViewport(0, 0, widthX, heightY);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture // load an image file directly as a new OpenGL texture
    (
        "img.jpg",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
         SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );
// allocate a texture name
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f);

    glEnd();

    drawFilledCircle(0.5f,0.5f,0.1f);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

UPDATE :

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(widthX, heightY);
    glutCreateWindow("earthQuake");
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyPressed);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyUp);
    /////////////////////////////////////
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   // glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    //glClearDepth(1.0f);
    //glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   // glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
   glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glutMainLoop();
```

widthX = 800; heightY = 400;

Comment: Looks like a viewport or projection aspect ratio issue. Are these set correctly?

Comment: Can you please post your code showing how you setup your viewport etc...?

Comment: see , the Update above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have misaligned viewport and window size ratios.

Following answer might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15725280/3301533

EDIT:

Thanks to this code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

You have your oval. Try changing it to:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-widthX/2, width/X2, -heightY/2, heightY/2, -1, 1);
```

Comment: i putted glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity(); for a full-screen texture effect , if i put your code the screen becames black

Comment: Notice that border coordinates are not (-1,1) now but `(widthX/2, heightY/2)` => change `glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f);` to `glVertex3f(-widthX/2.f, -heightY/2.f,  0.0f);` and the rest analogically

Comment: now the background texture disappeared  , but there is still the black oval

Comment: however , if i put this glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-widthX/2, widthX/2, -heightY/2, heightY/2, widthX/2, heightY/2);
glLoadIdentity();  , i see what i wrote before , but if i write this  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-widthX/2, widthX/2, -heightY/2, heightY/2, widthX/2, heightY/2);
the screen is black  , so i have to put two glLoadIdentity() to see something

Comment: As I said, you have to change your coordinates in vertices too to my code to work properly: `glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f);` should become `glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-widthX/2.f, -heightY/2.f,  0.0f);` etc for others. And try passing for example `50.f` as circle radius.

Comment: i did it , but the screen is black

Comment: if i put this double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH ) / 300.0;
double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) / 300.0;
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho( -1 * w, 1 * w, -1 * h, 1 * h, 10, -10); => the circle is a circle and it works , but the texture background is smaller and it doesn't cover of the window

Comment: if i change with this : glOrtho( -1 * w/2, 1 * w/2, -1 * h/2, 1 * h/2, w/2, -h/2); , the background texture is larger but doesnt cover the window sides

Comment: thanks it works !! , i placed double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH ) / 300.0; double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) / 300.0; glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); glLoadIdentity(); glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity(); glOrtho( -1 * w/2, 1 * w/2, -1 * h/2, 1 * h/2, w/2, -h/2); and ==> your advice glVertex3f(-w/2.f, -h/2.f,  0.0f);

Comment: Great you made this working. In case you need any explanation or further help don't hesitate to contact with me

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer showed one way of getting a circle, with the side effect of having to change your coordinates. I think this solution is generally more convenient, since you can still draw with the same coordinates you already had:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
double aspectRatio = (double)width / (double)height;
glOrtho(-aspectRatio, aspectRatio, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
```

Comment: it works but the background doesn't cover all the window

Comment: It doesn't clear the whole background when you call `glClear()`? That's hard to believe. The area that is cleared is not affected by transformations. The only way to restrict the pixels cleared by `glClear()` is the scissor test.